# How to validate the entire form on field blur instead of just the blurred field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that uses jQuery validation, using unobtrusive validation to declare rules. Currently I'm using the default submit behaviour where there is no validation on blur until the form is submitted (validating every field in the form), after which subsequent blurs validate just the blurred field.

I'd like to change this behaviour so that after a submit, blurring a single field revalidates the entire form, so that the error summary remains on screen until every issue has been addressed. The behaviour before submit should remain the same.

I've tried the following `onfocusout` methods based on other SO answers, with no luck:

```
onfocusout: function(element, event) {
    $(element).valid();
}
```

and

```
onfocusout: function(element, event) {
    this.element(element);
}
```

Comment: @Azim, absolutely not.  The `.valid()` method does not belong anyplace inside of the `.validate()` method as it could cause an infinite recursion.   Typically, `.element()` is the proper method for this when inside of `.validate()`... however, in this case, it appears that you cannot trigger validation of the entire form using this method.  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `this.element(element)` and `$(element).valid()` are for triggering validation on a single element.  In your case, since you're trying to apply this inside of the options of the `.validate()` or `.setDefaults()` methods, you cannot use `.valid()` as it could potentially trigger an infinite recursion.

That leaves `.element()`.  However, [as per the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/), you can only use this on a single field, not the entire form.

> **How to validate the entire form on field blur instead of just the blurred field**
>   
>   I'd like to change this behaviour ... blurring a single field revalidates the entire form

The solution would be to write an external `blur` event handler attached to all relevant input elements and trigger the `.valid()` method attached to your form.  Edit the selectors in this generic example for whatever is applicable to your particular form.

```
$('#myform input[type="text"]').on('blur', function() {
    $('#myform').valid();  // <- trigger validation on entire form
});
```

- `$('#myform input[type="text"]')` selects all text inputs within `#myform`
- `$('#myform') selects the`form`based on`id="myform"`

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation! As I have >200 different forms I've overridden the validator's default `onfocusout` to simply do `$(element.form).valid()` if `this.submitted` is empty so any element will validate whatever form it happens to be in, so long as there has been no initial submit of the form. I've added the same behaviour to the default `onkeyup` so validation messages.

Comment: Just a correction/addition to your answer. To validate a form you can also use `validator.form()` given that `validator = $("selector").validate()`. See https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/

Comment: @Arkni, true, but the `validator.form()` method, when used within the `.validate()` method, can also cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: @Sparky can you please elaborate on how `validator.form()` or `$(form).valid()` can cause infinite recursion?
From a code standpoint, I don't see how is that possible.

Comment: @Arkni, because there are certain the functions inside of `.validate()` such as `errorPlacement`, `highlight`, `unhighlight`, etc. are called every single time an element is validated.  So when you trigger `.valid()` from within those, it then triggers these functions inside of `.validate` again, which then call `.valid()` again, etc.  Since the developer provides a workaround in the form of  `this.element(element)`, you can easily avoid this potential scenario.